# How to get pandas.read_csv not to perform any conversions?

Tags: pandas

For example, the values in '/tmp/test.csv' (namely, `01`, `02`, `03`) are meant to represent *strings* that happen to match `/^\d+$/`, as opposed to integers:

```
In [10]: print open('/tmp/test.csv').read()
A,B,C
01,02,03
```

By default, `pandas.read_csv` converts these values to integers:

```
In [11]: import pandas

In [12]: pandas.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv')
Out[12]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
```

I want to tell `pandas.read_csv` to leave all these values alone.  I.e., perform no conversions whatsoever.  Furthermore, I want this "please do nothing" directive to be applied *across-the-board*, without my having to specify any column names or numbers.

I tried this, which achieved nothing:

```
In [13]: import csv

In [14]: pandas.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
Out[14]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
```

The only thing that worked was to define a big ol' `ConstantDict` class, and use an instance of it that always returns the identity function (`lambda x: x`) as the value for the `converters` parameter, and thereby trick `pandas.read_csv` into doing nothing:

```
In [15]: %cpaste
class ConstantDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.__value = value
    def get(self, *args):
        return self.__value
--
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
::::::
In [16]: pandas.read_csv('/tmp/test.csv', converters=ConstantDict(lambda x: x))
Out[16]: 
    A   B   C
0  01  02  03
```

That's a lot of gymnastics to get such a simple "please do nothing" request across.  (It would be even more gymnastics if I were to make `ConstantDict` bullet-proof.)

Isn't there a simpler way to achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`df = pd.read_csv('temp.csv', dtype=str)`

From the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
dtype : Type name or dict of column -> type, default None
Data type for data or columns. E.g. {‘a’: np.float64, ‘b’: np.int32} (Unsupported with engine=’python’). Use str or object to preserve and not interpret dtype.
```