# Trying to import all columns from a csv with an object data type with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I'm trying to read a csv into a new dataframe with `pandas`. A number of the columns may only contain numeric values, but I still want to have them imported in as strings/objects, rather than having columns of float type.

I'm trying to write some python scripts for data conversion/migration. I'm not an advanced Python programmer and mostly learning as I come across a problem that needs solving.

The csvs I am importing have varying number of columns, and even different column titles, and in any order, over which I have no control, so I can't explicitly specify data types using the `dtype` parameter with `read_csv`. I just want any column imported to be treated as an object data type so I can analyse it further for data quality.

Examples would be `'Staff ID'`, and `'License Number'` columns on one CSV I tried which should be strings fields holding 7-digit IDs, being imported as type float64.

I have tried using `astype` with `read_csv` and apply map on the dataframe after import

Note, there is no hard and fast rule on the contents of the type or quality of the data which is why I want to always import them as `dtype` of object.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me figure this out.

I've used the following code to read it in.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("agent.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1")
```

This creates the `'License Number'` column in `df` with a type of `float64` (among others).

Here is an example of License Number which should be a string:

`'1275595'` being stored as `1275595.0`

Converting it back to a string/object in `df` after the import changes it back to `'1275595.0'`

Comment: first you should read documentation for `read_csv`. There should be option to define convert for every column separatelly.

Comment: my understanding from the documentation is that I need to know the number of columns in order to define the conversion for each column separately. There could be 2 columns or 20. I've come up with some as much as 70 columns.

Comment: try `pd.read_csv(..., dtype=str)`. It should stop converting data.

Comment: [How to get pandas.read_csv not to perform any conversions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715038/how-to-get-pandas-read-csv-not-to-perform-any-conversions)

Comment: Cool. Thanks. Seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should stop converting data.

```
pd.read_csv(..., dtype=str)
```

Doc: [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
dtype: ...  Use str or object together with suitable na_values settings 
            to preserve and not interpret dtype.
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you split your csv reading process into multiple, specific-purpose functions.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Base function for reading a csv. All the parsing/formatting is done here
def read_csv(file_content, header=False, columns=None, encoding='utf-8'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file_content, header=header, encoding=encoding)
    df.columns = columns
    return df

# Function with a specific purpose as stated in the name.
def read_csv_license_plates(file_content, encoding='utf-8'):
    columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
    df = read_csv(file_content, True, columns)
    return df

read_csv_license_plates('agent.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
```