# Adding 0 in front of date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

New to programming:
I have a CSV file in which date is given in format `DDMMYYYY`, while reading the file in python its type is  taken as `int`. So a date say `01022020` is being taken as `1022020`. I need to add the `0` in front of all these dates wherein dates' `len` is less than `8`.

```
Index           Date              Value
0             10042020            10.5
1             03052020            14.2
2             09052020            16.3
3             13052020            17.5
```

I converted the column to `str` using `df.Date.map(str)` but can't understand how to proceed.

I tried:

```
if len(df.Date[i])==7:
        df.Date[i]= df.Date.str["0"]+df.Date.str[i]
```

Its not working. I have two queries regarding this:

1. want to understand why is this wrong logically and what's the best solution.
2. While reading the data from CSV file, can a column having integers only be converted to string directly?

Please help.

Comment: It should be `"0" + df.Date[i]`

Comment: You don't need `.str` because you already converted it to a string.

Comment: Why don't you just tell `read_csv` not to convert the date to a number? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715038/how-to-get-pandas-read-csv-not-to-perform-any-conversions/37715134

Answer (score 1):

```
 print(df)#input

     Index      Date  Value
0      0  10042020   10.5
1      1   3052020   14.2
2      2   9052020   16.3
3      3  13052020   17.5
```

convert date column to  string using `.astype(str)` and pad any strings whose len is less than 8 using `.str.pad()` method

```
 df['Date']=df['Date'].astype(str).str.pad(width=8, side='left', fillchar='0')

    Index      Date  Value
0      0  10042020   10.5
1      1  03052020   14.2
2      2  09052020   16.3
3      3  13052020   17.5
```

if needed in datetime object, then;

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d%m%Y')
```

Chained together;

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str).str.pad(width=8, side='left', fillchar='0'),format='%d%m%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use, `.str.zfill`:

```
s = pd.Series([1122020, 2032020, 12312020])
s
```

Input series:

```
0     1122020
1     2032020
2    12312020
dtype: int64
```

Use cast to string then use zfill:

```
s.astype(str).str.zfill(8)
```

Output:

```
0    01122020
1    02032020
2    12312020
dtype: object
```

Then you can use `pd.to_datetime` with `format`:

```
pd.to_datetime(s.astype(str).str.zfill(8), format='%m%d%Y')
```

Output:

```
0   2020-01-12
1   2020-02-03
2   2020-12-31
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I've seen for converting an int to a string that's left-padded with zeroes is to use the zfill command e.g. `str(df.Date[i]).zfill(8)`

Assuming you're using pandas for your csv load, you can specify the dtype on load: `df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={'Date': 'string'})`